# Can boxplot in base R display 'NA' when the grouping factor has missing values?

Tags: r, boxplot, missing-data

I want this:

[image: a boxplot with NA as a category name]

And I thought that passing `na.action=na.pass` to boxplot would let NA show up in 
the grouping names. Here is some sample code:

```
#Build a fake dataset
set.seed(212012)
nn = 100
sample_data <- data.frame( score = c( rpois(nn, 1), rpois(nn, 2),
                                      rpois(nn, 1.5), rpois(nn, 3)),
                          category = c( rep(0, nn), rep(1, nn), 
                                        rep(2, nn), rep(NA, nn) ))   

boxplot( score ~ category, data=sample_data, na.action=na.pass )
```

But that produces this:

[image]

The 'simple' way to get what I want is the following code, but it's not great for exploratory data analysis:

```
sample_data$category2 <- sample_data$category
sample_data$category2[ is.na(sample_data$category) ] <- 'NA'
boxplot( score ~ category2, data=sample_data )
```

Any hints from the R Guru's out there? I was able to find out about na.pass from [this more general discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557676/what-are-the-options-for-na-action-in-boxplot), and the origin of na.pass from [Prof. Ripley here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2004-May/029589.html). But there doesn't seem to be a distinction between missing data (NA's) appearing in the data that will be split by the factor and missing data in the factor itself. Am I missing something simple, or is this more of a feature request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boxplot( score ~ factor(category,exclude=NULL), data=sample_data)`

the default factor behavior is `exclude=NA`.  I assume internal to the `boxplot` call is a `factor` call if its not already a factor.  This is just forcing the factorization to include your NA values.

Comment: Also see `addNA` which does exactly that.

Comment: True!  `boxplot(score ~ addNA(category), data=sample_data)` Internally  `addNA` calls `factor` with `exclude=NULL`

Comment: I like `boxplot( score ~ addNA(category), data=sample_data)` as it is a little shorter. Thanks Justin & James!

Comment: `addNA` will add an NA category regardless of if one is needed or not.

Comment: @hadley thanks for the tip, given the chance I'd choose ggplot anyway!